# Deduce class in instance declarations

Tags: haskell

I am implementing functionality similar to Parsec, for pedagogical reasons. Motive is to define Functor, Applicative and Alternative instances without using Monad magic. Instances of Functor and Applicative are fine. However, defining `<|>` in Alternative is fraying my  hair.

```
newtype Parser t = Parser (String -> [(t, String)])

parse (Parser p) s = p s

instance Functor ....
instance Applicative ....

empty1 = Parser $ \s -> []

orp :: Parser t -> Parser t -> Parser t
-- orp :: (Eq t) => Parser t -> Parser t -> Parser t  -- this works too
p1 `orp` p2 = Parser $ \s -> let p1out = parse p1 s
                                 e     = parse empty1 s
                             in
                              if p1out == e
                              then parse p2 s
                              else p1out     

{- 
instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = Parser $ \s -> []

  (<|>) = orp -- fails to compile
-}
```

ghc complains that it could not deduce `Eq` from context, even if I add `Eq` to the signature of orp`. Obviously I cannot add a signature to an instance declaration to make it behave nice. Monomorphism restriction did not help; maybe I don't it understand all that well.

What am I missing? Should I explore existential types? Or am I making a fundamental mistake? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of comparing to an empty list using `(==)`, you should pattern-match

```
orp :: Parser t -> Parser t -> Parser t
orp p1 p2 = Parser $ \s ->
    case parse p1 s of
      [] -> parse p2 s
      xs -> xs
```

achieves the same behaviour without type class constraints and is therefore usable in the instance declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Fischer suggested a concrete fix; I'd like to suggest an abstract fix. Along the way, we'll expose a design decision that you've made here that you may not have even realized you made (and I'll make the case that you decided incorrectly).

It is [well known](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/TypeCompose/0.9.1/doc/html/Control-Compose.html#t%3a%3a.) that applicative functors compose; it is somewhat less well-known (though certainly not invented by me) that many other kinds of functor pairings compose. In particular, an alternative functor composes with a functor on either side to produce a new alternative functor. Below, I'm going to use Haskell syntax to explain what I mean. I'll be writing *invalid* Haskell -- because I'll be using `type` instead of `newtype` everywhere to avoid clutter -- but we'll use the invalid Haskell to derive valid Haskell later.

```
type (f :. g) a = f (g a) -- like in TypeCompose

-- (1)
instance (Applicative f, Alternative g) => Alternative (f :. g) where
    empty = pure empty
    x <|> y = liftA2 (<|>) x y

-- (2)
instance Alternative f => Alternative (f :. g) where
    empty = empty
    x <|> y = x <|> y
```

(These instances overlap a really, really lot.)

Semantically, we can now view your type as a chain of type compositions:

```
-- (3)
type Parser = (String ->) :. [] :. (String,)
```

...where here we observe that `(String ->)` is an instance of `Applicative` (4) and `[]` is an instance of `Alternative` (5). This means that we ought to be able to just "read off" an instance of `Alternative` from this by coupling the semantic definition of `Parser` with the instances above.

```
empty :: Parser t
= -- (3)
empty :: (String ->) :. [] :. (String,)
= -- (1)
pure (empty :: [] :. (String,)) :: (String ->) :. ([] :. (String,))
= -- (4)
const (empty :: [] :. (String,)) :: (String ->) :. ([] :. (String,))
= -- (2) to use []'s empty rather than [] :. (String,)'s empty
const (empty :: [] :. (String,)) :: (String ->) :. ([] :. (String,))
= -- (5)
const [] :: (String ->) :. ([] :. (String,))

p <|> q :: Parser t -> Parser t -> Parser t
= -- (3)
p <|> q :: ... -> ... -> ((String ->) :. [] :. (String,))
= -- (1)
liftA2 (<|>) p q
= -- (4)
\s -> p s <|> q s
= -- (2) to use []'s <|> rather than [] :. (String,)'s <|>
\s -> p s <|> q s
= -- (5)
\s -> p s ++ q s
```

So, semantically, we know how we want `empty` and `<|>` to behave now for `Parser`s, and the only trick remaining is to add in all the appropriate newtype constructors and deconstructors.

```
instance Alternative Parser where
    empty = Parser (const [])
    Parser p <|> Parser q = Parser (\s -> p s ++ q s)
```

Or, if we felt exciting, we could write the same thing with more overloaded syntax:

```
instance Alternative Parser where
    empty = Parser (pure empty)
    Parser p <|> Parser q = Parser (liftA2 (<|>) p q)
```

Notice that this implementation of `(<|>)` actually always returns all the results from `q`! In your definition, `q` only gets to return its parses when `p` fails; that means in particular that the list of successful parses will be left-biased. The semantically-driven implementation above has no such bias: even if the left-hand side of a `(<|>)` parses, the right-hand side will be allowed to tell about its triumphs, too. And I think this is quite natural: it means that a parser built with this interface will return *all* successful parses.

What is the difference practically? Well the semantic definition above is *more robust*, and the definition you proposed is *more efficient*. Let's see what "more robust" means first.

Consider a parser which always consumes exactly one character (what it returns will be unimportant for this discussion):

```
oneChar = Parser (\s -> case s of
    c:cs -> [((),cs)]
    _    -> [])
```

...and a parser which always succeeds without consuming any characters:

```
epsilon = Parser (\s -> [((),s)]) -- you might recognize this as "pure ()"
```

Now, what happens if we compose a one-or-two-character parser like this?

```
oneOrTwo = (oneChar <|> epsilon) <* oneChar
```

Consider using `oneOrTwo` to parse `"a"`. With your definition of `(<|>)`, the first part, `oneChar <|> epsilon`, tries to use `oneChar` to parse a bit, which succeeds, and hence never runs `epsilon`, and we get a list of parses like `[((),"")]`. But now the second part fails: there is no one character left to parse. With my definition of `(<|>)`, the first part instead tries both parses, which runs both `oneChar` and `epsilon`, and we get a list of parses like `[((),""),((),"a")]`. Now the second part fails on the first element of that list, but succeeds on the second, and the parse overall succeeds.

On the other hand, your definition can be more efficient for two reasons: first, it can throw away early parts of the input sooner (leading to better interactions with garbage collection), and second, it can prune large parts of the backtracking search space (leading to fewer cycles spent searching).

This tradeoff is quite well-known; for example, [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) provides both your kind of alternation (which commits to its first argument if it ever consumes any input) and my kind (which does backtracking) via the [try](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3atry) combinator.